# SQL Select to combine records where all but two columns are same, the two columns one will be empty or not exists

Tags: sql, join, merge

[image: table, last two columns retain column names]

I want to select all distinct records from the table except the last two columns, if all other cols match new record with both values returned vs two separate records.

Comment: Which RDBMS?  What query have you tried?  Why didn't it work?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, Start-Date, End-Date, c5m c6, c7 FROM <YourTable>

Comment: I am just full on blank on what I want to accomplish... I normally have a identifier that I could use to case if c8 then c8 else 0 end as c8 but just blank staring at this now.

Comment: Alexander, yes, that looks good, but then joining back and adding the two columns?

Comment: Which values from `c8` and `c9` do you want to return per row (there could be many for the same distinct record)?

Comment: @BarryS Could you provide example what you wish to see in output result?

Comment: Is this logic right... if I get the distinct c1- c7 and join back on all 7 columns

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT w1.[c1]
      ,w1.[c2]
      ,w1.[Start-Date]
      ,w1.[End-Date]
      ,w1.[c5]
      ,w1.[c6]
      ,w1.[c7]
   ,w2.[c8]
   ,w2.[c9]
   FROM w w1
   INNER JOIN  w w2 ON w1.[c1] = w2.[c1]
      and w1.[c2] = w2.[c2]
       and w1.[Start-Date] = w2.[Start-Date]
       and w1.[End-Date] = w2.[End-Date]
       and w1.[c5] = w2.[c5]
       and w1.[c6] = w2.[c6]
       and w1.[c7] = w2.[c7]

Comment: Goal is these two rows would become 1...  c1 c2 Start-Date End-Date c5 c6 c7 c8 c9
n1 bb 20171203 20171209 2 222 xxx 0 0.1
n1 bb 20171203 20171209 2 222 xxx 4 0
1 thru 7 same, then c8 is "4" and c9 is "0.1"

Comment: @BarryS SELECT c1, c2, Start-Date, End-Date, c5, c6, c7, MAX(c8) AS c8, MAX(c9) AS c9 FROM w GROUP BY c1, c2, Start-Date, End-Date, c5, c6, c7

Answer (score 0):

Ok... embarrassed.  Luckily the last two values are numeric value, so grouping on the first seven columns and sum(c8) sum(c9) returned desired result; from 17 records to 11

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  c1,
  c2,
  Start-Date,
  End-Date,
  c5,
  c6,
  c7,
  MAX(c8) AS c8,
  MAX(c9) AS c9
FROM w
GROUP BY c1, c2, Start-Date, End-Date, c5, c6, c7
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Could you say something about how this is working? The OP did not post any code to begin with.